# How Cmake comes to know about Installed Libraries on Ubuntu System?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, dynamic-linking

I just installed OpenCV and PCL Libararies on my system (ubuntu 16.04). In my C++ project's CMakeLists.txt I have following commands:

```
find_package(PCL Required)
find_package(OpenCV Required)
```

I know, find_package is in Module mode. Though, in default Cmake 3.10 does not come with FindOpenCV.cmake neither FindPCL.cmake e.g. there is no similar files in

> /usr/share/cmake/Modules

neither in

> /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules

Why Cmake is not giving error ? I tried to find these files by find command in root directory but could not find anywhere.

Comment: Maybe those libraries installed their stuff in some predefined folders, such as `/usr/local/lib` `/usr/local/include`

Comment: I found  a `CMake` module `OpenCVConfig.cmake` at  `/usr/share/OpenCV` in ubuntu-18.04 under WSL.

Comment: @VTT yes I kow, I found those directories. But could not find any cmake moudle or conifg file.

Comment: @drescherjm I could not find in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are file `FindOpenCV.cmake` (Module mode) or `OpenCVConfig.cmake` (Config Mode) in you file system.

You can find then by cmd: `sudo find / -iname "*opencv*.cmake"`